# Swagger Integration with spring boot

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

For one of the rest call `/rest/task/addAttachmentToNote` which is `POST` request, I'am getting `OPTIONS`and `PATCH` being displayed in the Swagger UI. Why?
[image]

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: @jmattheis My Controller is,
`@ApiOperation( value = "Add Attachment to Note", response = AttachmentToNoteBean.class, responseContainer = "List", httpMethod = "POST" )
    @RequestMapping( value = "/addAttachmentToNote", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<?> addAttachmentToNote( @RequestBody
    final Map<String, Object> noteAttachment, final HttpServletRequest request )
    {`